# Angular 2 auth seems not to work, although I receive a success message

Tags: angular, http, authentication

I set up an auth with Node, and it works fine with e.g. Postman. But in Angular, it seems I did something wrong. I created a service and the auth() function is called on button click.

When I click the button, I can see that I receive a 200 status, and I receive the success message that I created in the backend. I want to redirect to the /dashboard a successful login, but somehow I receive a 401 unauthorized error (a GET function is called in the DashboardComponent). The credentials are 100% right (otherwise I wouldn't receive a success mesage). Like I said, it works on Postman.

What did I do wrong? Thank you !

Here is the code of the service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { env } from '../../../../.env';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';

import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Injectable()
export class LoginService {

  constructor(private _http : Http, private router: Router) {}

  public auth(creds) {
    return this._http
        .post(env.apiUrl + '/api/auth', creds)
        .map((response:Response) => {
          return this.successfulAuth(response);
        });
  }

  private successfulAuth(response) {
    response = response.json();
    if(response.success === 1) {
      // this works !
      this.router.navigateByUrl('/dashboard');
    }
    return [];
  }

}
```

Comment: are firing any apis when loading the `DashboardComponent` ?

Comment: Yes, a GET-call! Am I doing anything wrong? @phegde

Comment: if you are using JWT based authentication, you need to pass tokens for every API calls. If you don't pass you might get a 401. And I don't see you saving any token on successful login.

Comment: I use Express with Passport, just session-based, no JWT. I don't send any additional headers in Postman either. That's why I am confused

Comment: OK, I found the problem: API is on localhost:3100 and Angular app on localhost:4200 - probably something with the CORS settings. I'll check it

Comment: CORS shouldn't trouble you in localhost.